# Disable users from clicking the Submit button if he already clicked it in the paste 7 minutes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to disable the 'Submit' button for 7 minutes and I want a text next to the form saying: "Wait 7 minutes before submitting". And when the countdown is down, I want a text saying "You can submit now".

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input name="statusid" autocomplete="off" id="statusid" placeholder="Enter ID" required="" type="text">
    <button name="submit_btn" class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: And what did you try yourself? And you are aware that anyone even the slightest bit proficient in webdevelopment can bypass this 'security' in seconds?

Comment: I have Googled that problem but didn't find any code for a button submit, all I find is an input submit.

Comment: *"I have Googled"* is not an attempted solution. What code have you written already yourself to attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: I have made a form, but it's just showing "Submit" in the question I just asked, this is the form: 
<form action="" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" class="form-wrapper cf">
 <input name="statusid" autocomplete="off" id="statusid" placeholder="Enter ID" required="" type="text">



 <button name="submit_btn" class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: For future, try to use http://jsfiddle.net/ for any code.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this securely would be with server side validation. This means that the server must store somewhere (preferably a database) the last time a user clicked the submit button. This also means you'll need a user account system.

Obviously you can update the time last clicked when a submission goes through successfully. If unsuccessful, you can return the number of minutes remaining, and have JavaScript create the countdown timer from that. However, the timer should be just for convenience. The actual validation for if enough time has passed should be purely server side.

Technically, you could implement this in JS, using cookies to keep track of the user, but it'd be very easy to get around (delete the cookie or modify the page's source). You shouldn't do this in JS.

Comment: That's what I want, but whats the code for that? sorry I am new and not good at databases and stuff :)

Comment: Then you have a lot to learn before this question even becomes relevant. This site is not the forum for teaching you databases, authentication, etc. in a single post. Do some research, read some books, and then when you have a specific question to ask you're more than welcome to post here to have it answered.

Comment: It doesn't work in this way. we don't ever know what you are using on the server side. What language, databse etc.

Comment: @user3184573 There's too much code to go over in a single post here. Do you have any experience with a server side language (PHP, JS with Node.js, Python with Django, etc)? You'll need to learn one of those. The server side language would interact with the database. The exact methods used depend on the language. For example,  PHP would use the [MySQLi class](http://ca3.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: If you want to store information for a user in a database then you have A LOT more work to do / learn. start playing around with MySql/PHP (WAMP) (its free), then come back and present your question when you can demonstrate a basic understanding and have some PHP/MySql code to show.

Comment: I have a website that doesn't really need DB, I only use PHP, HTML, JS & CSS that's all. What I want is a script that makes the user/visitor to wait 7 minutes before submitting the form, the problem is that the form uses an <button> Submit. not a <input> submit, that's why I posted my question here. How is my question not clear?

Comment: @user3184573 The use of a button or input doesn't matter. The information should still be sent to the server for processing and validation.

Comment: There is another form on my website that uses a <input> submit and I have found a script that makes the user wait 7 minutes before submitting, I have tried the SAME script on the <button> submit but it didn't work, I guess it DOES matter :)

Comment: So it's done in the way that no one should do. Probably it's just js validation. and you have somewhere in the script input instead of button. It would be more helpful if you would give us a link

Answer (score 2):

I see in the comments from another answer that you are using PHP but not a database.  If that's all you want to use then you can take this approach....

(1) When the user clicks the button and submit the form you need to set a PHP session variable holding the current time.  So if the users submits the form to say `doSomething.php` then in there where you are processing the form data set `$_SESSION['formSubmitTime'] = microtime(true);`

(2) Then back on your page that contains the form you read `$_SESSION['formSubmitTime']` and compare it to the current time.  If it's been more than 7 minutes then turn your button on.

```
$time_end = microtime(true);
$secondsElapsed = $time_end - $_SESSION['formSubmitTime'];

echo "Form submitted $secondsElapsed seconds ago\n";
```

If `$secondsElapsed` is greater than 420 then show the button, else disable it.

(3) That should get you where you want to go.  But you could take it even a step further and not require them to refresh the page.  To do that you would have to do the code above but then set a JavaScript countdown starting at the correct number based on the seconds already elapsed.  So lets say `$secondsElapsed` above was 100 seconds.  Then you would have JavaScript code that would do a `setTimeout` after 320 seconds (420sec=7min) (420-100=320sec left).  So that would look something like this... `setTimeout(function(){ /*your code to turn the button back on*/ },320000);`

**UPDATE --** Thanks for posting your form code.  Here is a more complete example.  (this was quickly free typed so it may have some typos but should be plenty to get you pointed in the right direction.)  Hope this helps.

```
<script>
    function allowSubmit(){
        //change the text
        $("#msgText").text('You can submit the form again.');
        //enable the button
        $("#submit_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
</script>

<?php
//If $_SESSION['formSubmitTime'] is not defined then that means they have never submitted.  So they don't have to wait
if (!isset($_SESSION['formSubmitTime']))
{
    $secondsToWait = 0;
}
else
{
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $secondsElapsed = $time_end - $_SESSION['formSubmitTime'];  //remember to set this back on the page you post to
    $secondsToWait = 420-$secondsElapsed;
}

echo'
<form action="" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);" class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input name="statusid" autocomplete="off" id="statusid" placeholder="Enter ID" required="" type="text">
    <button name="submit_btn" class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit" '.$secondsToWait > 0?"disabled":"".'>Submit</button>
</form>';

if ($secondsToWait > 0)
{
    echo'<span id="msgText">You must wait '.$secondsToWait.' seconds.</span>
    <script>setTimeout(function(){ allowSubmit() },'.$secondsToWait.'000);</script>';
}
else
    echo'<span id="msgText">You can submit the form again.</span>';
?>
```

Comment: This is quick solution and probably enough for him, but remember that it's not secure in anyway.

Comment: Right, Just answering in a way he can understand.

Comment: Hi @gfrobenius, I have done steps 1 & 2, but I don't really understand the "If $secondsElapsed is greater than 420 then show the button, else disable it." part, will you please explain a little bit for me? thanks :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user3184573 Just skip down to the full example.  I posted that update after you posted your form.  Use that code.  @MaciejPaprocki what's not secure here, there's no XSS possibility as `$secondsToWait` will only hold numbers.

Comment: Hi @gfrobenius, can you please add me on skype? my id: sajadleo
I will show you my website and the form that I have there, you can view the source and see the whole form I have, it would be great if we can talk about that on skype, thank you very much! :)

Comment: It's not secure because users can do whatever they want with session. So basically they can get instant access by just changing the number in the session. They can use js console for example.

Comment: I really need to do that form timer, I will lose a lot of users if I don't make it as fast as possible :)
I have tried the code you gave me and it always says "You can submit". Even if I already submitted in the past 7 minutes

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki True. I'm just demonstrating front end. I assume everyone knows the importance of server side validation. That's a MUST for sure!

Comment: @user3184573 I've never used Skype, I sent you a "contact request". I only 5 minutes to spare.

Answer (score 0):

Even that question is asked without any specifications I think I might get some hints to help other people coming there. I will call this thing event locking problem :).

First of all without proper authorization (Closed registration or facebook gmail etc.). It will never be actually secure. The question is what you can do to make it harder to breach.

The easiest to do and easiest to breach is just js script. Disabling button for 7 minutes using `jQuery('button').prop('disable',true)` (from jQuery library)  and than adding `setTimeout(function(){jQuery('button').prop('disable',false)})` should do the trick. However to breach this you just need js console or even firebug. In little bit better way you can also add cookie on disabling button and check it when enabling button. However console and firebug will win once again.

Another security we can add already uses the back end technologies.

1.We start the countdown by creating file or database record(I highly recommend to use database, but sometimes you don't have or just don't use database anywhere else) with two things: unique key from now on called id (different every time so for example `AUTO_INCREMENT`) and time stamp (if we have multiple buttons or events we can also use event/button id). Then we are sending this unique id as cookie to user browser(if we have multiple events we send pair id and button/event id).
2.On the frontend we create script added as in first case. after user clicks the button, back end script checks if the id from cookie have timestamp older than 7 minutes and if yes it pass the file. If not it return error or whatever you want. We can also add ajax for checking every 30 minutes for example how much is left in this case if someone will for example shut the browser or whatever we can always show them the proper amount of time left. The longer (harder) you will do the unique id, the stronger will be the script, because it will be just harder to just try to use some id used by different user. In case of using previously mentioned `AUTO_INCREMENT` you can just hash this id to some complicated string.

This solution will stop 90% of spammers. But mostly because 90% of them doesn't know anything about coding. Actually dealing with cookies is never so easy when it comes to writing bots.

Another way to do this is to add to your record (only DB option) IP of the user. In this case they will not be able to just catch someone else cookie, becaue they will also have to catch their IP which is already a lot harder. This will also elimnate this people that can wait 7 minutes but don't want to wait another minutes later for downloading. For example by starting counter 1000 times, and than getting 1000 results after 7 minutes (which should take them 7000 minutes). It's enough to give just one request for everyone on the same ip. However this have some cons. What will happen if two people are using this same wifi for example? One of them will locked for 7 minutes.

The last and the bast way to do it is to use authorization. Use user id and store it with time stamp than just check if user with this id timestamp took more than 7 minutes. However if our system is not done properly it's not really hard to use bot to register for new accounts. It's why closed registration (user cannot register on their own and you are doing it manually checking their credibility) is better. You can use also social profiles. However registration is open there, but whole process is a lot harder and fake accounts are all the time closing because of administrators check their access.

I hope this post will help someone. It's one of my first posts in here and first one that I spend so much time, so I would really appreciate some feedback and of course suggestions how to improve my answer. If this will be deleted, because of bad quality question I will just add it as a tip :)